# yarp with signalr .net core 5/6

Tags: .net, signalr, ms-yarp

I have created a basic chathub with signalr and want YARP to forward all the WS://<>/chat/ trafic to my API service; could anyway please share the YARP config file just to forward all the websocket traffic to an endpoint.

Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have YARP running already, just provide the config via app settings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/path/to/match/{*path}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster1": {
        "Destinations": {
          "cluster1/destination1": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5000/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have something a bit more concrete that you're playing with locally that is not working, please provide it here and I'll help if I can. For more details, check out the [YARP docs](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html), the above config is mostly a copy paste of their out of the box config.